# Access value from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I generate my array using this code: `$array = get_field('footballers','option');`.

I then run `print_r($array);` and get the following output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 75
    [name] => John Barnes
    [slug] => john-barnes
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 77
    [taxonomy] => theme
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 18
    [object_id] => 1089
    [filter] => raw
)
```

How do I access the `slug` key from my array, so I can have a `$slug` variable?

Thank you

Comment: That's not an array. You can access that key using `$array->slug`, or to get a `$slug` variable, `$slug = $array->slug;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$array->slug;
```

It's an object, not array.